# How to convert h.264 (MP4) to Theora (FFmpeg)

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, ogg, theora

How to convert h.264 to Theora using FFmpeg.
I generally use all the -qscale commands etc, but the quality is hopeless anyway. The point is that the movie freezes after a few seconds and only keyframes are shown.
I know there is another converter but I need a solution in FFmpeg.

Comment: Show your command and the complete log. Which player are you using?

Comment: Please see: [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xV6KC2CuW_-G1KkkvAaa1socAg46xqQ0?usp=sharing]. Command: ffmpeg -i test-video.mp4 -c:v libtheora -q:v 7 -c:a libvorbis -q:a 4 output.ogv 2>log.txt

Comment: 1) I can't duplicate the issue using the same ffmpeg version and same input (on Linux, libtheora 1.1.1). Output looks normal here. 2) Why do you want Theora? There are better, more modern alternatives such as VP9.

Comment: I distinguish two reasons here:
1) Could you please give me specific information about the environment you use? I probably won't miss a ffmpeg compilation, but it's always worth a try.
2) I am looking for a good alternative to H.264 and H.265 (AVC and HEVC). I took into account VP8 and VP9 and so far I have to check all the possibilities.

Comment: 1) Arch Linux. Tested ffmpeg master and your particular version. Your libtheora version is currently unknown, but since it's so mature I don't expect it to be too important 2) Most [browsers that support Theora also support VP9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support), so I recommend using that instead and forgetting Theora.

Comment: Hi
I'm closing this thread because I tried converting on linux with a newer version of ffmpeg and all other libraries and the problem is gone.
Thank you very much for your help, because if you hadn't mentioned I'd probably still be lost. My windows version of ffmpeg was quite old, possibly libtheora too. Of course, I will take into account your suggestions from the VP9. After viewing the link, it will likely use VP9 on the pages as a backup or in some cases the main codec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am closing thread because I tried a newer version of ffmpeg on linux.
For people who will have a similar problem:

## Try converting on linux

Choose the distributions for you.

#### If you are a beginner, read about Ubuntu or Linux Mint as they are very popular and easy to use for beginners.

When you know more, you have already chosen yours.

## Install the latest version of FFmpeg with libraries.

---

You will probably need to compile FFmpeg, all useful links are on their site.

In case you can't do it, I recommend opening a thread on the forum.
Use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i imput.mp4 -c: v libtheora -q: v 10 -c: a libvorbis -q: a 10 output.ogv
```

Match the values of -q: v and -q: a. these are quality values

Comment: Note: for the `-c` and `-q` parameters, I needed to omit the spaces and write `-c:v`, for example.

Comment: No spaces after colons. I didn't have to write the codecs libtheora and libvorbis. They are chosen by default for OGV.